# Eclipse Luna: Keyboard shortcut is causing strange text editing behaviour

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the keyboard shortcut that I keep accidentally pressing that causes Eclipse to underline text and interfere with all other shortcuts? (e.g. Ctrl+Backspace to delete a word, Ctrl+Space to auto complete.)

I have looked through the shortcuts and cannot find what it could be.

This is what text looks like when I activate it:

[image: Text underling]

As you can see "test" is underlined, as was "int" before that. This seems to be the indicator that this "troll-mode" is activated.

Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1) Build id: 20140925-1800
OS: Arch-Linux

---

**UPDATE:** This was caused by an IME that I had installed and uninstalled a month ago, but hadn't rebooted since. Thanks!

Comment: Check the errors: in Eclipse, Windows->Show View->Error Log

Comment: This sounds to me like some sort of [IME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method_editor). It might be the OS that's doing it, rather than Eclipse itself.

Comment: Lots of entries under "Keybinding conflicts occurred". I tried pressing all the ones it mentioned but it didn't recreate the problem. I don't have any IME configured, but I will look into that - thanks.